# connect to xbox using Windows Media Center

Tags: streaming, xbox-360

Is there any software available for ubuntu that can emulate Windows Media Center for connecting a computer to an xbox? I tried following the xbox wizard, but it says that I need Windows.

I just want to be able to choose to show pictures, play music or video on my tv through my xbox instead of my computer.

I can currently do something similar using my Samsung phone and wireless TV using AllShare. I just choose which video I want to play and where and it works like magic.

The TV my xbox is connected to though doesn't have wireless so I was hoping to use the xbox for similar functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rygel` to run a upnp/dlna server on your computer. I use it, and it works well for streaming music and movies to both my Xbox and PS3.

Comment: thanks, this works to some extent. Are there any rygel indicators so I don't have to use a terminal to run it? A banshee/rhythmbox/nautilus plugin to allow me to 'push' media to devices would be great, but maybe I'm dreaming too big.

Comment: I don't think there is an indicator. But if you copy the /usr/share/applications/rygel.desktop file into your ~/.config/autostart/ directory, it should start automatically when you log in. If you run apt-cache search rygel, you can see there are several related packages available as well. If you wanted to, you could write a plug-in for rygel, and one for banshee/rhythmbox/nautilus/whatever so that rygel only streams stuff which you "push" to it, but that is much more complex.